How do I relate input and output signals and find the output for other input signals in LTI system?
I am studying about signals and systems. I came across a few practice problems. For the below question, I was able to mimic the input and output waves shown in Figure 2.7.2 in desmos here.

I know x(t) is a unit pulse that such that, $$x\left(t\right)=u\left(t\right)-u\left(t-1\right)$$
I also know y(t) is a triangular pulse (since it's given that input was x(t) i.e. an unit pulse) such that $$y\left(t\right)=\int_{0}^{t}u\left(t\right)dx-3\int_{0}^{t-1}u\left(t-1\right)dx+3\int_{0}^{t-2}u\left(t-2\right)dx-\int_{0}^{t-3}u\left(t-3\right)dx$$


I'm not sure if my above equations for input and output signals are correct. I only think they are because they match the question input and output signals.

I know I would need to calculate the LTI system's transfer function h(t) (via y(t)=x(t)*h(t) or h(t)=y(t)/x(t)). I have three questions,

Are my above input output equation's correct for the below question?
Should I just do y(t)/x(t) to get my transfer function h(t)?
Once I have my transfer function h(t). How do I calculate the output y2(t) for other inputs like x2(t)?



I solved it. The know how a system's perform's to various outputs, you'll need to find the system's transfer function. The system's transfer function is given by \$H(s)=\frac{Y(s)}{X(s)}\$ where \$H(s)\$ is the transfer function, \$Y(s)\$ is the s-plane representation of output signal \$y(t)\$ and \$X(s)\$ is the s-plane representation of input signal \$x(t)\$.
Since the question above gives both the input and output signal. We can convert both of them to their s-plane representation by performing a Laplace operation on each of them.

Converting both input and output signal to s-plane.

The Laplace of input signal \$x(t)=u(t)-u(t-1)\$ is \$X\left(s\right)=\frac{1-e^{-s}}{s}\$.
The Laplace of output signal \$y(t)=u(t)-u(t-1)\$ is \$Y\left(s\right)=\frac{\left(1-3e^{-s}+3e^{-2s}-e^{-3s}\right)}{s^{2}}\$.


Find the transfer function \$H(s)\$

Since we now have both \$X(s)\$ and \$Y(s)\$. We can substitute them in \$H(s)=\frac{Y(s)}{X(s)}\$.
This would result in \$H\left(s\right)=\frac{\left(1-3e^{-s}+3e^{-2s}-e^{-3s}\right)}{s(1-e^{-s})}\$.


Calculate for other inputs.

Now you can figure out the system's output for input via simply rearranging the original \$H(s)=\frac{Y(s)}{X(s)}\$. You can rewrite this as \$X(s)*H(s)=Y(s)\$ or \$Y(s)=X(s)*H(s)\$.
Just substitute other input signals for \$X(s)\$ and substitute your previously calculated transfer function. You'll get the output signal \$Y(s)\$.
Remember these answers are still in s-plane representation so after you find \$Y(s)\$ you'll have to convert back into time domain representation to get the answer. This is done by the Inverse Laplace operation on \$Y(s)\$ which will give you final \$y(t)\$.



Coming back to the questions asked!

Are my above input output equation's correct for the below question?

Yes! The output signal \$y(t)\$ is supposedly a infinite signal that goes to infinity but for calculation you can assume it goes to some finite "n" say "2" when integrating to find the s-plane representation.


Should I just do y(t)/x(t) to get my transfer function h(t)?

Yes!


Once I have my transfer function h(t). How do I calculate the output y2(t) for other inputs like x2(t)?

Rearrange as shown in Step 3 above.



